# ¿Por que al imprimir un valor en arduino me imprime este cuadro?

Tags: array, arduino, datos

Estoy obteniendo datos en un arreglo byte de 80 posiciones.
Creo unas variables las cuales seran remplazadas en el arreglo **leerdatos[80]**

```
byte leerdatos[80];

byte y1 = 2;
byte y2 = 3;
byte m1 = 1;
byte m2 = 1;
byte d1 = 2;
byte d2 = 0;
```

Imprimo el arreglo leerdatos[80] de la siguiente manera

```
for (byte i = 0; i <= 80; i++){
    Serial.print(char(leerdatos[i]));
}
```

Y me muestra lo siguiente:
[image: El arreglo leerdatos[80] sin modificaciones]

Luego yo mismo cambio los valores de las posiciones 18-23 de este mismo arreglo con esas variables tipo byte que cree.

```
leerdatos[18] = y1;
leerdatos[19] = y2;
leerdatos[20] = m1;
leerdatos[21] = m2;
leerdatos[22] = d1;
leerdatos[23] = d2;
```

El inconveniente es el siguiente cuando imprimo el nuevo array al que ya le hice modificaciones:
[image: Aparecen los cuadros como si no se pueden leer los datos correctamente]
El cual imprimo de esta misma forma:

```
for (byte i = 0; i <= 80; i++){
    Serial.print(char(leerdatos[i]));
}
```

Lo que quiero es que los caracteres que modifique se puedan mostrar correctamente cuando yo vuelva a acceder al arreglo con el char().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la variable `y1` tienes el valor entero 2, pero lo que quieres dejar en la línea de texto es el caracter ASCII correspondiente. El truco usual es aplicar la formula:

```
caracter = char('0' + valor)
```

Con `'0'`, interpretado como entero, obtenemos el valor del caracter cero. Si le sumamos `1`, obtenemos el valor del caracter '1', etc.

#### Demo

```
void setup() {
  byte leerdatos[] = "La mona jacinta se ha puesto una cinta";
  
  byte y1 = 2;
  byte y2 = 3;
  byte m1 = 1;
  byte m2 = 1;
  byte d1 = 2;
  byte d2 = 0;  
  
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println();  

  leerdatos[18] = '0' + y1;
  leerdatos[19] = '0' + y2;
  leerdatos[20] = '0' + m1;
  leerdatos[21] = '0' + m2;
  leerdatos[22] = '0' + d1;
  leerdatos[23] = '0' + d2;

  for (byte i = 0; i <= strlen((const char *) leerdatos); i++){
      Serial.print(char(leerdatos[i]));
  }
}

void loop() {
  
}
```

produce:

```
La mona jacinta se231120esto una cinta
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, se pudo solucionar.

Answer (score 2):

Los cuadros que ves se deben a qué intenta imprimir carácteres sin un símbolo asociado.

Cada carácter en realidad es un valor numérico que le corresponde un símbolo.

Según [la documentación](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/char/), usa el código ASCII para este propósito.

Los números del 0 al 31 son códigos de control sin símbolo. 2, 3, 1, 1, 2 y 0 están dentro de ese rango.

Si lo que quieres es convertir, por ejemplo 0 al carácter '0' debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
byte digito = 4;
char caracter = '0' + char(digito);
```

Con eso aprovechas que los símbolos de los números son consecutivos en el código ASCII.

Pero si quieres convertir un número de 2 cifras o más tienes que usar [`String`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/) o implementar tu propio algoritmo que haga la conversión:

```
int n = 256;
// Convertir a string "256"
String str = String(n);
// Convertir a string binario "100000000"
String strBin = String(n, BIN);
```